# I'm getting overfull \hbox

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a total newbie to LaTeX, so I apologize in advance if the solution was very simple.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}










\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        




\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]

%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300




%Shape: Circle [id:dp10731740866095518] 

\draw   (100,119.3) .. controls (100,113.06) and (105.06,108) .. (111.3,108) .. controls (117.54,108) and (122.6,113.06) .. (122.6,119.3) .. controls (122.6,125.54) and (117.54,130.6) .. (111.3,130.6) .. controls (105.06,130.6) and (100,125.54) .. (100,119.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp8550853927719966] 

\draw   (130,119.3) .. controls (130,113.06) and (135.06,108) .. (141.3,108) .. controls (147.54,108) and (152.6,113.06) .. (152.6,119.3) .. controls (152.6,125.54) and (147.54,130.6) .. (141.3,130.6) .. controls (135.06,130.6) and (130,125.54) .. (130,119.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp8369920364834502] 

\draw   (160,119.3) .. controls (160,113.06) and (165.06,108) .. (171.3,108) .. controls (177.54,108) and (182.6,113.06) .. (182.6,119.3) .. controls (182.6,125.54) and (177.54,130.6) .. (171.3,130.6) .. controls (165.06,130.6) and (160,125.54) .. (160,119.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp039951208327267285] 

\draw   (190,119.3) .. controls (190,113.06) and (195.06,108) .. (201.3,108) .. controls (207.54,108) and (212.6,113.06) .. (212.6,119.3) .. controls (212.6,125.54) and (207.54,130.6) .. (201.3,130.6) .. controls (195.06,130.6) and (190,125.54) .. (190,119.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp13502049396629356] 

\draw   (70,119.3) .. controls (70,113.06) and (75.06,108) .. (81.3,108) .. controls (87.54,108) and (92.6,113.06) .. (92.6,119.3) .. controls (92.6,125.54) and (87.54,130.6) .. (81.3,130.6) .. controls (75.06,130.6) and (70,125.54) .. (70,119.3) -- cycle ;

%Straight Lines [id:da6004352202226555] 

\draw    (220.6,119.2) -- (272.6,119.2) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da06504066824061616] 

\draw    (272.6,119.2) -- (300.6,89.2) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da7113505895463899] 

\draw    (300.6,150.2) -- (272.6,119.2) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da7465140938989834] 

\draw    (300.6,89.2) -- (329.6,89.2) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da7124724087262677] 

\draw    (300.6,150.2) -- (329.6,150.2) ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp5996319730736912] 

\draw   (371,89.3) .. controls (371,83.06) and (376.06,78) .. (382.3,78) .. controls (388.54,78) and (393.6,83.06) .. (393.6,89.3) .. controls (393.6,95.54) and (388.54,100.6) .. (382.3,100.6) .. controls (376.06,100.6) and (371,95.54) .. (371,89.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp6103000286264326] 

\draw   (401,89.3) .. controls (401,83.06) and (406.06,78) .. (412.3,78) .. controls (418.54,78) and (423.6,83.06) .. (423.6,89.3) .. controls (423.6,95.54) and (418.54,100.6) .. (412.3,100.6) .. controls (406.06,100.6) and (401,95.54) .. (401,89.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp3258415864979445] 

\draw   (341,150.3) .. controls (341,144.06) and (346.06,139) .. (352.3,139) .. controls (358.54,139) and (363.6,144.06) .. (363.6,150.3) .. controls (363.6,156.54) and (358.54,161.6) .. (352.3,161.6) .. controls (346.06,161.6) and (341,156.54) .. (341,150.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp5723827322091124] 

\draw   (371,150.3) .. controls (371,144.06) and (376.06,139) .. (382.3,139) .. controls (388.54,139) and (393.6,144.06) .. (393.6,150.3) .. controls (393.6,156.54) and (388.54,161.6) .. (382.3,161.6) .. controls (376.06,161.6) and (371,156.54) .. (371,150.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp5412197464046806] 

\draw   (401,150.3) .. controls (401,144.06) and (406.06,139) .. (412.3,139) .. controls (418.54,139) and (423.6,144.06) .. (423.6,150.3) .. controls (423.6,156.54) and (418.54,161.6) .. (412.3,161.6) .. controls (406.06,161.6) and (401,156.54) .. (401,150.3) -- cycle ;

%Straight Lines [id:da05630625336350281] 

\draw    (429.6,149.2) -- (510.6,149.2) ;

\draw [shift={(512.6,149.2)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da97407370700205] 

\draw    (412.6,146.2) -- (412.6,155.2) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da3707513408135563] 

\draw    (412.6,146.2) -- (408.6,151.2) ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp8347286516909556] 

\draw   (521,150.3) .. controls (521,144.06) and (526.06,139) .. (532.3,139) .. controls (538.54,139) and (543.6,144.06) .. (543.6,150.3) .. controls (543.6,156.54) and (538.54,161.6) .. (532.3,161.6) .. controls (526.06,161.6) and (521,156.54) .. (521,150.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp41289375858181576] 

\draw   (551,150.3) .. controls (551,144.06) and (556.06,139) .. (562.3,139) .. controls (568.54,139) and (573.6,144.06) .. (573.6,150.3) .. controls (573.6,156.54) and (568.54,161.6) .. (562.3,161.6) .. controls (556.06,161.6) and (551,156.54) .. (551,150.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp6318783898627132] 

\draw   (581,150.3) .. controls (581,144.06) and (586.06,139) .. (592.3,139) .. controls (598.54,139) and (603.6,144.06) .. (603.6,150.3) .. controls (603.6,156.54) and (598.54,161.6) .. (592.3,161.6) .. controls (586.06,161.6) and (581,156.54) .. (581,150.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp07014785405225399] 

\draw   (551,89.3) .. controls (551,83.06) and (556.06,78) .. (562.3,78) .. controls (568.54,78) and (573.6,83.06) .. (573.6,89.3) .. controls (573.6,95.54) and (568.54,100.6) .. (562.3,100.6) .. controls (556.06,100.6) and (551,95.54) .. (551,89.3) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp41439340735458163] 

\draw   (581,89.3) .. controls (581,83.06) and (586.06,78) .. (592.3,78) .. controls (598.54,78) and (603.6,83.06) .. (603.6,89.3) .. controls (603.6,95.54) and (598.54,100.6) .. (592.3,100.6) .. controls (586.06,100.6) and (581,95.54) .. (581,89.3) -- cycle ;

%Straight Lines [id:da9778268941199351] 

\draw    (592.6,85.2) -- (592.6,94.2) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da2130505623304222] 

\draw    (592.6,85.2) -- (588.6,90.2) ;

%Straight Lines [id:da04942318820076008] 

\draw    (619.6,163.2) -- (619.6,66.2) ;

\draw [shift={(619.6,64.2)}, rotate = 450] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

%Flowchart: Alternative Process [id:dp0407532678261171] 

\draw   (109,218.17) .. controls (109,220.4) and (110.8,222.2) .. (113.02,222.2) -- (571.57,222.2) .. controls (573.8,222.2) and (575.6,220.4) .. (575.6,218.17) -- (575.6,203.22) .. controls (575.6,201) and (573.8,199.2) .. (571.57,199.2) -- (113.02,199.2) .. controls (110.8,199.2) and (109,201) .. (109,203.22) -- cycle ;




% Text Node

\draw (429.5,149.1) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\scriptsize d-d transition after }\\{\scriptsize absorbption of $\Delta$ E}};

% Text Node

\draw (622,108) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\Delta$ E};

% Text Node

\draw (209,200) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {absorption of yellow light by [Ti(H$_{2}$O)$_{6}$]$^{3+}$};







\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

It renders the Tix image I want but shows me the error `Overfull \hbox (47.95255pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 180--181`, which is the code `\end{tixpicture}`
I don't understand how I am supposed to shorten that.
If you have any suggestions, please do let me know.

Comment: This is not really an error but just a warning. Does it bother you like that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @SebGlav I actually use LaTeX on Anki. It doesn't bother me while working on Overleaf or other LaTeX console. But it doesn't render it on Anki for no reason, and shows me that error at the end of the log.

Comment: I don't know where you found this code but using `218.17` as coordinate is pretty useless and weird. For the kind of picture rendered, is it necessary to use so large coordinates (`(622,108)`)? Why the hell draw those complex Bezier curves to draw just... plain circles? Hence the very long first compiling. You would be well advised to start your picture from scratch.

Comment: why `\special{papersize=3in,5in}` ??? This does nothing at all if you use pdflatex,  if you use latex+dvips it sets the size of the PDF to a size that doesn't match the size used by LateX for typesetting.

Comment: @SebGlav the reason is that I don't know how to use TiKz, like, at all. I use this website called Mathcha which lets me draw on it, and it codes for me, which I can then insert in my Anki cards.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know this sounds irresponsible but I really don't understand how any of this functionality works. I use the website under the name Mathcha which lets me draw on it and it codes the TeX for me.  It's worked flawlessly for the past couple of times I've used it, and has only failed me this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is just telling you that the tikzpicture is bigger than the page so you can make it a bit smaller by changing

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
```

to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-.8,xscale=.8]
```

Comment: This fixed the problem, thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

Just to follow my comments, here's an example of what you can do in five minutes which produces more or less the same output without any error. Not the best way to do it but it would be easy to understand if you want to learn a bit how Ti*k*Z works.

[image: absorption of yellow light]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    
        \def\r{1}
        \foreach \i in {0,...,4} \draw (2.5*\i,0) circle (\r);

        \draw   (11.5,0) -- (15,0) --++ (2,2) --++ (2,0)
                (15,0) --++ (2,-2) --++ (2,0);
                
        \foreach \i in {0,...,2} \draw (20.5+2.5*\i,-2) circle (\r);
        \foreach \i in {1,2} \draw (20.5+2.5*\i,2) circle (\r);
        \node at (25.5,-2){\Huge 1};

        \draw[-{Stealth[length=8pt]}] (27,-2) --++(6,0) node[below=2pt,midway,text width=5cm,align=center]{d-d transition after\\absorption of $\Delta E$};
        
        \foreach \i in {0,...,2} \draw (34.5+2.5*\i,-2) circle (\r);
        \foreach \i in {1,2} \draw (34.5+2.5*\i,2) circle (\r);
        \node at (39.5,2){\Huge 1};
        
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=8pt]}] (41,-3) --++(0,6) node[right=2pt,midway]{\Large $\Delta E$};
        \node[rounded corners, minimum width=10cm,draw] at (21,-6) {\large absorption of yellow light by [Ti(H$_{2}$O)$_{6}$]$^{3+}$};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the most helpful and far less complex but as I've mentioned under my question, I don't really understand it's functionality because I rely on the program.
Still, this is plenty helpful so, thanks a lot for your time and support